# How to create a loop with R function specgram(signal)

Tags: r, loops, signals, spectrogram

I am working with many signals; each one in a time series but is too many and, I need to make more than 1000 but,  I am not sure how to implement it because I not only need the plots but the values of output for each spectrogram stored in a file or an R object. I am sorry I don't have an approach. Can anyone help out, please?

Comment: Hi @Lucy_biostat It would be helpful to include an example as a starting point for what you are trying to do. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Are your signal files in a directory that `list.files(` could find them?

Comment: My signals are in a  R df  with 1 signal per row but I used as.matrix  for convert it in a numeric matrix.